# Evaluation of EL during view build time in c:forEach

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jstl, el

What happens with EL statements in a view build time in c:forEach loop.

```
<c:forEach var="v" values="#{bean.values}">
    <p:inputText value="#{v.name}" />
</c:forEach>

class Bean {
   public List<Pojo> getValues();
}

class Pojo {
   public void setName (String);
   public String getName();
}
```

How will be this code  evaluated for render? To:

```
 <p:inputText value="John Smith">
```

or

```
 <p:inputText value="#{pojo.name}" >
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For UI components, only `id` and `binding` attributes are immediately evaluated during view build time. All other attribtues are deferred. I.e. they will get an instance of [`ValueExpression`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/el/ValueExpression.html) (or [`MethodExpression`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/el/MethodExpression.html)) instead of the immediately evaluated value. The `ValueExpression` is re-evaluated on every individual `getValue()`/`setValue()` call.

#### See also:

- [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)

Comment: Thank you! If I understand your answer correctly, the reference for each object in a collection will be saved in `ValueExpression` (or somewhere) and then EL will be reevaluated in render phase.

Comment: Nope, it's the EL expression itself (in flavor of `String` with exact value `#{pojo.name}`) which is saved. It's re-executed on every `getValue()`/`setValue()` call.

Comment: Ok, I understand that EL expression will be saved. But how the EL expression know for which object (in my example Pojo-class) to call the getter/setter. The reference to object should be saved somewhere. Is it saved in `ELContext` parameter of `getValue() / setValue()` ? Or from your comment the evaluated String-value will be saved ?

Comment: Each iteration has its own EL context, indeed. In case of Mojarra, it's `com.sun.facelets.tag.jstl.core.ForEachFaceletContext`